# Why doesn't search operation work in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been stuck in this problem since hours.When i click on submit button it doesn't respond Just refreshes the page.

controller for Index

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Students.ToList());
}

[HttpGet,ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string option, string search)
{
    if (option == "Name")
    {
        var a = db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentName == search || search == null);

        return View(a.ToList());
    }
    else if (option == "Gender")
    {
        return View(db.Students.Where(x => x.Gender == search).ToList());
    }
    else
    {
        return View(db.Students.Where(x => x.RegNo == search || search == null).ToList()) 
    }
}
```

Index View

```html
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Student",FormMethod.Get)){
    <div id="search">
        <b>Search By:</b>@Html.RadioButton("option","Name")<b>Name</b>
        @Html.RadioButton("option","Gender")<b>Gender</b>
        @Html.RadioButton("option","Dept")<b>Dept</b>
        @Html.RadioButton("option","RegNo")<b>RegNo</b>
        <input type="text" name="text" />
        <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default"/>
    </div>
}
```

What can be done to solve the problem?

Comment: Your input is not connected with the controller. The name in input must have the same name with the search string like `name="search"`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of that method. Does it get hit when you submit? What are the values of the parameters, especially "search"?

Comment: i have just changed in the INPUT tag with name="search" and it works, but when i search first letter of name/gender it show blanks

Comment: @roni that is because you check `x.Gender == search` : in other words, the gender must be *equal* to the search text. Maybe a `x.Gender.StartsWith(search)` will work, but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can give more results

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string search)
{
var students = from s in db.Students
                   select s;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        students = students.Where(s => s.StudentName.Contains(search)
                               || s.Gender.Contains(search));
    }
return View(students.ToList());

}
```

I don't know your requirement but when you search data to db you need just one or two properties from this data.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Student",FormMethod.Get)){
    <div id="search">
        <input type="text" name="search" />
        <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default"/>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Create a POST. GET is used to request data. You are attempting to send data back (the search parameters) which requires a post back.</strike>

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult SearchIndex()
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost,ActionName("Index")]
 public ActionResult SearchIndex(string option, string search)
    {
      if (option == "Name")
      {
        var a = db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentName == search || search == null);

        return View(a.ToList());
      }
      else if (option == "Gender")
      {
        return View(db.Students.Where(x => x.Gender == search).ToList());

      }
      else
      {
        return View(db.Students.Where(x => x.RegNo == search || search == null).ToList()) 
      }
    }
```

The html will also need to be updated to use FormMethod.Post in the using.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new { encType = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

**EDIT**
On second thought, I think you only need the multipart/form-data added to your html.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Student", FormMethod.Get, new { encType = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: GET can send data back just as well as POST.

Comment: `encType = "multipart/form-data"` is to allow uploading of files. Its not necessary in OP's case (they do not have a file input)